# How reliable age certification at Google Play is?

Tags: google-play-store

So far I've been trusting in PEGI certifications nearly as in bible.

Today, I found [Alchademy game](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hyperbeard.alchademy), which has **PEGI 3** age certification, but deeply in the game's desc you can find something like this:

> This game is not intended for children and may have some content that is inappropriate for children under the age of 13.

Please, explain, what am I missing? How can a game pass PEGI 3 certification with such a note?

Based on above, I come with the conclusion that PEGI certifications at Google Play are completely worthless and when deciding whether particular app is or isn't applicable for my children, I must always dig description or -- the best -- install and play the game myself.

If that's truth then what is the reason in fouling people with that whole PEGI stuff at all?

Comment: You can, and probably should, flag the app as "improper content rating" in Google Play.

Comment: I did, as you suggested, nearly immediately, even before your suggestion has popped out. Unfortunately, this is pointless as it turned out that Google Play's age ratings are pretty much worthless. They're not based on application producer's disclaimer, but rather are the result of some semi-automatic algorithm that is based on some questions asked to the app's producer. Above is a pretty example that neither these questions nor the mentioned algorithm are working. See the answers below for more details. Thank you.

Comment: Totally off-topic... But until this post I only knew "PEGI XX" from the beginning of game trailer videos on various sights, and thought they were a video hosting server or something (Content delivered by PEGI 13 or something like that). Wow, was I wrong! Apparently this system has been in effect since 2003, and I highly doubt most people in the US have any clue what it is. Do Europeans know what the ESRB is?

Comment: @trejder I'd argue that the system is not worthless but probably the best you can get without having a human screen each and every app. Of course it is not perfect and can be gamed, but then again, that is why you can flag the app as inappropriate.

Comment: @acejavelin Not really, but we have our own ratings USK in germany and PEGI. That is why the play store provides ratings for most system on the globe and tries to show you the localized match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** I don't develop Android apps so my answer might be lacking. I hope our residents developers will provide more clarifications if necessary.

According to [Content ratings for apps & games](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/188189?hl=en), The rating of an app is done by independent 3rd-parties not Google. The app's developer fill a rating questionnaire, then independent 3rd parties rate it:

> To receive a rating for each of your apps and games, you fill out a rating questionnaire on the Play Console about the nature of your apps’ content and receive a content rating from multiple rating authorities.  Since they are independent third party rating authorities, each rating authority uses their own methodology to assign your ratings (see Rating authorities & descriptions below). The ratings assigned to your app displayed on Google Play are determined by your questionnaire responses.

It is possible based on the last sentence that the responses to the rating questionnaire prompted the rating agencies to rate the app PEGI 3 while the developer(s) state(s) even on their own [website](https://hyperbeard.com/game/alchademy/) that:

> This game is not intended for children and may have some content that is inappropriate for children under the age of 13

Thus, the app should be rated [PEGI](https://pegi.info/what-do-the-labels-mean) 12. As a comparison, the game is rated +9 on the [Appstore](https://apps.apple.com/app/id1156716750).

The rating can be inconsistent as shown [here](https://techcrunch.com/2019/10/23/googles-play-store-is-giving-an-age-rating-finger-to-fleksy-a-gboard-rival/) where keyboard apps with the same content are not rated the same:

> The Fleksy app, which has been on the Play Store for around eight years at this point — and per Play Store install stats has had more than 5M downloads to date — was PEGI 3 rating until earlier this month. But then Google stepped in and forced the team to up the rating to 12.

---

> That’s not the end of the saga, though. Google’s Play Store team is still not happy with the regional age rating for Fleksy — and wants to push the rating even higher — claiming, in a subsequent email, that “your app contains mature content (e.g. emoji) and should have higher rating”.
>
> Now, to be crystal clear, Google’s own Gboard app also contains the middle finger emoji. We are 100% sure of this because we double-checked…

In the case, of the link article above, it was Google that forced the rating change not independent 3rd parties. After the developers complained to [International Age Rating Coalition](https://www.globalratings.com/), the rating was then restored. It shows that Google can manipulate the rating.

Answer (score 1):

While *Reddy Lutonadio*'s answer actually fulfils the subject, I'd like to add my own, since I have received an answer and clarification from the creators of the game in question:

> We understand the confusion that this can create, we place the information corresponding to the app, but in the case of the App rating, we have no control over it, this because Google assigns it automatically after some questions.

Based on above, I think we can clearly say that Google Play's age rating are pretty much worthless.

Comment: I do think the app publisher has some control over the app rating, according to https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/188189# he could use https://www.globalratings.com/developer-contactus.aspx to ask IARC to adjust the rating. Sadly, there is less incentive for the publisher/developer to do so: a low age rating means that the app is available for more users (children), which means more revenue from advertisement and in-app sales.